# How to log authentication result with OWIN Jwt Bearer Authentication

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, jwt, owin

I want to log stats for all calls to my .netcore webapi.

I have added a `IAsyncActionFilter` for this purpose and it picks up on all the actions.

But I also have Jwt Bearer Authentication enabled and am using the `AuthorizeAttribute` on my controller to limit access. When access is denied the Action filter will not be hit.

Whats the best way to add some custom logging (statsd) for authentication in general and failures in particular?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
....
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            // base-address of your identityserver
            options.Authority = Configuration["Authority"]; ;

            // name of the API resource
            options.Audience = "myAudience";
        });
...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
...
    app.UseAuthentication();
...
}
```

I Notice that `JwtBearerOptions` has `JwtBearerEvents Events` but I cant get this to work.

**Edit** : It looks like I am hitting the api with no token at all and the JWT Auth handler returns AuthenticateResult.NoResult() without calling the Events.AuthenticationFailed

https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/ba1eb281d135400436c52c17edc71307bc038ec0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/JwtBearerHandler.cs#L63-L83

**Edit 2** : Very frustrating. Looks like the correct place to log would be in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter` But this is automatically added when you use `[Authorize]` and is impossible to override, remove or replace?

Answer (score 7):

The JwtBearerOptions.cs class exposes an JwtBearerEvents parameter where you can declare your events like this

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        // base-address of your identityserver
        options.Authority = Configuration["Authority"]; ;

        // name of the API resource
        options.Audience = "myAudience";

        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
            {
                //Log failed authentications
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            },
            OnTokenValidated = context =>
            {
                //Log successful authentications
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };

    });
```

Comment: yes, ive done that. it doesnt call OnAuthenticationFailed when there is no token

Comment: @Ewan u are correct. The JWT middleware dont do anything if doesn't find a token in the HTTP request. I thought that was what u wanted, to log the failed authentications. ok, if you want to log all requests then add a logging mddleware before the authentication middleware

Comment: hmm thats where my thoughts are leading me. I guess if i change the filter to middle ware and put it in first I will be able to detect the failed or successful auth somehow?

Comment: the odd thing is it must be the authhandler for the authorizationAttribute which kills the request and its not clear where that fits into the middleware.

Comment: Yes, if you place the middleware first you could log all responses and check the context if the user is authenticated or not. just await _next(context) and check the context response. here's an example https://gist.github.com/elanderson/c50b2107de8ee2ed856353dfed9168a2

Comment: it seems like you would basically have to rewrite/reverse engineer both the auth middleware and the authattribute to work out what happened from the context though. not very elegant

Comment: @Ewan u are right. An other option is to make a pull request and modify the jwt middleware to log OnMissingToken event :)

Comment: hmm maybe, I was going to raise an issue, but it seems like its by design. The attribute seems like the correct place, because even of the token is valid you could fail on allowed roles. But all discussion is about how you dont touch it and make policies instead

Comment: Works with .net core 3 too. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

I don´t have any experience with Jwt Bearer Authentication - but we´ve had a similar situation. We´ve ended up with a new BaseController where we´re able to Log basic user information and distinguish between `[AllowAnonymous]` and `[Authorize]`:

```
public class NewBaseController : Controller
{
    protected UserManager<MyUser> UserManager;
    protected MyUser CurrentUser;
    protected ILogger Logger;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);

        UserManager = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<UserManager<MyUser>>();

        var loggerFactory = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
        Logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(GetType());
        // Check if Action is annotated with [AllowAnonymous]
        var controllerActionDescriptor = context.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
        var anonymousAllowed = controllerActionDescriptor.MethodInfo
            .GetCustomAttributes(inherit: true)
            .Any(a => a.GetType().Equals(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute)));

        if (!anonymousAllowed)
        {
            ApplicationUser = UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result;
            if (ApplicationUser == null)
                // do some stuff
            Logger.LogInformation("User is {UserId}", CurrentUser.Id);
        }
        else
        {
            Logger.LogInformation("User is {User}", anonymous);
        }
    }
 }
```

Bonus: Every Controller that derives from this base already has an instance of UserManager, ILogger and CurrentUser.

Hope that comes close to what you´re looking for...

Comment: hi. I gave it a quick go, but it looks like the controllers OnActionExecuting isnt called as the Authentication Filter from the AuthorizeAttribute is hit first?

Comment: ps. im not sure if its relevatn but my [Authorize] is on the controller

Comment: pps. no I moved it and it still doesnt run

Comment: Ok.. It was worth a try, I think :) as I mentioned, I wasn´t sure, if it works with Jwt.. Hope you´ll find your solution